# Set libblas and liblapack used by R per user (not global/systemwide) Debian Linux 10

Tags: r, linux, user-permissions, lapack, blas

I can set the default BLAS/LAPACK for my system and subsequently used by R via:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

which updates the BLAS/LAPACK used for all users. I would like to pick a BLAS/LAPACK without effecting the BLAS/LAPACK usage in R for all other users.

I have also tried changing my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my `.bashrc` to:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

without changing (even after logging out and in again) the default BLAS/LAPACK used by R (checked by `sessionInfo()`).

Seperate VMs for users would work and maybe Docker, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to solve this question using the following sources:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/10/installing-and-switching-to-mkl-on-fedora/ and https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/10/switch-blas-lapack-without-leaving-your-r-session/.

In short, I used [R's flexiblast library](https://github.com/Enchufa2/r-flexiblas), itself a wrapper around [flexiblas](https://www.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/projects/flexiblas) to indicate which BLAS/LAPACK to use for each user. After changing the system-wide BLAS/LAPACK to `flexiblas`, I included the following lines in my `.Rprofile`

```
library(flexiblas)
flexiblas_load_backend('OPENBLASPTHREAD')
# [1] 2
flexiblas_switch(2)
```

or when I want to load the Intel MKL BLAS/LAPACK which isn't installed under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and thus not recognized by name like `OPENBLASPTHREAD`:

```
library(flexiblas)
flexiblas_load_backend("/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so")
# [1] 2
flexiblas_switch(2)
```